# Importing OCX Into XE2 Shows "Library not registered" Error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, ocx

In Delphi XE2, I have a project that builds an OCX. Once it is built, I then register the OCX using regsvr32. Then I import the ActiveX control component to the same XE2 environment so I can test it.

Unfortunately, when I do the import, the IDE is showing me the following error:
[image: Error reported by XE2 when trying to add an ActiveX OCX as a component]
Other questions similar to this in SO usually have answers about the OCX not being registered or a dependency not being registered, but in my case neither of those are valid.

Any DLL's required for the OCX are registered and installed properly, otherwise the project would not build and produce the OCX.

The OCX is properly registered as the CLSID's related to it are in the registry, and it was in the list of registered ActiveX controls that I chose during the import process.

While it would be nice if XE2 would tell me what user-defined type it was trying to use, or what library it thinks is not registered, given that I am lacking that information does anyone have any other ideas on what may be causing the problem?

Comment: "Any DLL's required for the OCX are registered and installed properly, otherwise the project would not build and produce the OCX." - this assumption might be wrong. There could be a required type library declaration missing in your type library or one of its dependencies.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: When you registered it, did you use the Regsvr32 from the Windows\SysWOW64 folder?